# Difference in handling Get-ChildItem between PowerShell and PowerShell ISE?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise, powershell-5.0

I'm getting a difference in the handling of `Get-ChildItem` between running it in a PowerShell window and in the PowerShell ISE

Test directory with 5 fives, test01.txt though test05.txt

```
$orbdata = 'C:\spool\RBDEV\data'
$srcfiles = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $orbdata -Filter *.txt)
$srcfiles.Length
```

In PowerShell window, I get the result I expected, i.e. 5

But in the ISE, same script gives result 54, i.e. the length of the string ...

```
test01.txt test02.txt test03.txt test04.txt test05.txt
```

Any suggestion as to why?  *... and even better, how to fix it!*

Comment: Something is missing here. If nothing else this script is incomplete since we don't see `$orbdata`. No, it should not matter but what you describe should not happen. What PowerShell version are you using.

Comment: @Matt if `$orbdata = '.'`, it could happen :)

Comment: @matt got v5 installed

Comment: ISE starts in a different directory, apparently.

Comment: @SteveC We still don't know what `$orbdata` is

Comment: if path is the same then the only difference has to be permissions related

Comment: I think it should be ... $orbdata = 'C:\spool\RBDEV\data'

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen You can reproduce this?

Comment: Exactly the same script? That would happen if you did `"$srcfiles".Length`, or something else similar to force the array into a string.

Comment: I can't reproduce it.